# Dexie function return item after seaching

Tags: javascript, indexeddb, dexie

I have a simple Dexie table search function that I want to return the searched item after the searching code is actually run

```
function ReturnItemFromTable() {
  db.table1
   .where('field1')
   .equals('some value')
   .first(function(item) {
     return item
  }
}
```

So I know the 'return' in the above code is in the wrong place for the function to know it's supposed to be returned. But if I put it in the right place it gets returns before the table.where has had a chance to run and thus returns undefined.

Is there a way to get this ordering done right?

Thanks,
Frank

Comment: Louis, I had already seen your answer because it came up while I was searching for answers prior to asking my question posted here. And while it is an educational source for a person like me who is somewhat new to the concepts of asynchronous programming, it was not at all an exact duplicate of my question.

Answer (score 0):

Put a 'return' before 'db.table1' and your function will return a Promise that will resolve with the result.

To call it:

```
ReturnItemFromTable().then(function (result){
    alert('got ' + result);
}).catch (function (error) {
    alert (error);
});
```

Comment: Yep, that worked like a charm. Thanks so much!